# Angular 6 Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 3'

Tags: angular6, ngfor

I guess I just do not understand how ngFor works. Why does angular check the value so many times? Keep in mind, that I want the value to be updated. Please explain, because I feel completely lost.

To give some background info:

I have a product page that checks the shopping cart items and displays how many items are in the shopping cart of a particular product. Currently, it is displaying 11, when there are only two items in the shopping cart.

The shopping cart is kept in localStorage as an object listing the items that a user has added to the cart. I can see in Chrome dev tools> Application> cart - the object and how many items it contains.

The following is my Product model, which is the same structure as my shopping cart object:

```
export interface Product {
  product: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string;
    price: string;
    ts: string;
    product_image_id: number;
    product_image: string;
    enabled: boolean;
    counter: number;
  };
}
```

The following is the getTotalItems(item) method that counts how many items are in the shopping cart of a particular product, which basically increments the item.counter when there is a match to the product's id:

```
 getTotalItems(item) {
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    for (let u = 0; u < this.cartObj.cart.products.product.length; u++) {
      if (item.id === this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].id) {
        item.counter += this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].counter;
      }
    }
  } else {
    item.counter = 0;
  }
  return item.counter;
}
```

Notice that item.counter is being updated within the for loop, but the for loop should only be available for the two items in the shopping cart. I want to know why does angular try to update it 11 times:

```
for (let u = 0; u < this.cartObj.cart.products.product.length; u++) {
  if (item.id === this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].id) {
    item.counter += this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].counter;
  }
}
```

The following is the html that calls the geTotaltItems(item) method, from the shopping cart service, along with filteredProducts coming from my product service, located in the constructor of the product component:

```
 this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
  this.filteredProducts = this.products = resProd.products;

    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredProducts; let i = index">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ item.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ item.price | currency }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-2">
                <button
                  (click)="removeFromCart(item)"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="col text-center">
                {{ this.cartSrvc.getTotalItems(item) }} in cart
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <button
                  (click)="addToCart(item)"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                >
                  +
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

In the getTotalItems method, I place the following console.log:

```
console.log("item.id: " + item.id + "item.counter: " + item.counter);
```

At first, it was working just fine, finding the item.id and the counter would increment as it found a matching id in the shopping cart. In my case, there were only two items in the shopping cart:

[image: As you can see by the screenshot, the product page loads just fine, with the exception that it is not showing the number items in the shopping cart correctly]

[image: This is a screenshot of Chrome dev tools showing the contents of the cart and the error]

As you can see, once it passed the second item, it continued to check, which causes the error.

My question is basically, why will it not stop once the for loop has gone through all the items in the shopping cart? In this case, there are only two items, why does Angular keep checking after the two items?

Thanks in advance

BTW, I have also tried to limit how much getTotalItems is called, by doing the following, with the same results:

```
             <div
                *ngIf="item.counter > 0; else justZero"
                class="col text-center"
              >
                {{ this.cartSrvc.getTotalItems(item) }} in cart
              </div>
              <ng-template #justZero>
                <div class="col text-center">0 in cart</div>
              </ng-template>
```

Comment: I don't see any `ngFor` in the posted code. The "card" is within it, I suppose?

Comment: @Jeto, thank you for replying - the ngFor is above the code that I pasted in - <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredProducts; let i = index"> - just like any other ngFor that I have made

Comment: What is `filteredProducts`? You're asking why your loop isn't stopping, so I feel like this is a critical thing to share. And the error suggests you're modifying its contents during the loop. In any cas, you should probably edit your question rather than posting it in comment btw. Also, consider creating a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) if you can (but maybe we can help without).

Comment: @Jeto, thanks for replying. filteredProducts is what is being returned from my product service. The products load just fine. I only want the items from the shopping cart to appear under each product. In this case, there are only two items in the shopping cart, but angular counts 11. There are fifteen products. Please concentrate on the getTotalItems(item) method. If I remove this from the html, the products load just fine without any error and thank you once again

Comment: @Jeto, I have updated the post to give more info

Comment: OK, I now understand what's going on, and it's unrelated with `ngFor`. Give me a few minutes, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related to `ngFor`.

In your `getTotalItems` function, that you call from your template, you have to make sure that calling it twice with a given item will produce (return) the same result. Otherwise, Angular will detect that the method that was used to display it also modified it, which is forbidden.

In your case, calling it twice in a row with the same item will not yield the same result, because you never reset `item.counter`.

You have two ways to solve this.

### First way

Change your `getTotalItems` code to the following:

```
getTotalItems(item) {
  item.counter = 0;
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    for (let u = 0; u < this.cartObj.cart.products.product.length; u++) {
      if (item.id === this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].id) {
        item.counter += this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].counter;
      }
    }
  }
  return item.counter;
}
```

Here, you always reset the counter to 0, and increment it only if there's a cart in the local storage.

### Second way (recommended)

The second way requires you to store the counter *before* calling your template, and is recommended because it's usually considered bad practice to call component methods within a view (as they will not only be called once).

Your component code becomes:

```
this.filteredProducts.forEach(item => item.count = this.getTotalItems(item));
```

And change `getTotalItems` to this:

```
getTotalItems(item) {
  let count = 0;
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    for (let u = 0; u < this.cartObj.cart.products.product.length; u++) {
      if (item.id === this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].id) {
        count += this.cartObj.cart.products.product[u].counter;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Then, from your view, you can simply do:

```
{{ item.count }} in cart
```

Comment: Thank you for helping @jeto I was doing some reading, which lead to me finding that your statement of "Angular will detect that the method that was used to display it also modified it, which is forbidden" is correct. As a result, I have removed the function from the html, but I am still not receiving the correct item.counter. I tried both of your suggestions. At first, it looks like it is working when I click the "addToCart" buttons of a product, but then, if I click on another product, the first product's item numbers triple. I did want to thank you for at least helping me understanding why

Comment: @kronus You're welcome! Well, I'd have to see the code of `addToCart`, because from the code you posted I don't see what clicking on it would do.

Answer (score 0):

I had to refactor every thing. Thanks to @jeto, along with reading a few articles, I learned that it is not a good practice to place a function within the html as I had done:

```
          <div class="col text-center">
            {{ this.cartSrvc.getTotalItems(item) }} in cart
          </div>
```

Once again, as @jeto said, "Angular will detect that the method that was used to display it also modified it, which is forbidden"

As a result, I scrapped almost everything. The only thing that shopping cart services does now, is to read the localStorage.getItem('cart') where the shopping cart is being stored, followed by using the contents to fill shoppingCartObj, which in turn, is used to display the items in the shopping cart.

The following is my products html now:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredProducts; let i = index">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card product-card">
          <img
            class="card-img-top"
            src="{{ oshopUrl + 'uploads/' + item.product_image }}"
            alt="{{ item.name }}"
          />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ item.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ item.price | currency }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-2">
                <button
                  (click)="removeFromCart(item, '-')"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="col text-center">{{ item.counter }} in cart</div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <button
                  (click)="addToCart(item, '+')"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                >
                  +
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div *ngIf="(i + 1) % 2 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is the product's component relevant to this discussion:

```
 addToCart(item, operator) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    if (item.counter === null || typeof item.counter === "undefined") {
      item.counter = 1;
    }
    this.text = "";
    this.createCart(item);
    console.log("makes it to createCart");
  } else {
    if (item.counter === null || typeof item.counter === "undefined") {
      item.counter = 0;
    }
    this.updateCart(item, operator);
    console.log("makes it to updateCart");
  }
  this.incrementCartState();
}

createCart(item) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    this.shoppingCartObj = this.addItemToShoppingCart(item);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(this.shoppingCartObj));
  }
}

addItemToShoppingCart(item: Product) {
  if (this.text === "") {
    this.text = this.makeOrderId();
    console.log("this.text: ", this.text);
  }
  this.productArr.push(item);
  this.shoppingCartObj = {
    cart: {
      user_id: this.loginSrvc.loginObj.uName,
      orders_id: this.text,
      ts: TimeSt.mTstamp(),
      products: {
        product: this.productArr
      }
    }
  };
  this.getPriceTotal();
  // this.updateFilteredProducts();
  return this.shoppingCartObj;
}

updateCart(item, operator) {
  // console.log("from updateCart item: ", item);
  const index = this.productArr.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.productArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  if (operator === "+") {
    item.counter += 1;
  } else {
    item.counter -= 1;
  }
  this.productArr.splice(this.productArr.length, 0, item);

  this.shoppingCartObj = {
    cart: {
      user_id: this.loginSrvc.loginObj.uName,
      orders_id: this.text,
      ts: TimeSt.mTstamp(),
      products: {
        product: this.productArr
      }
    }
  };
  this.getPriceTotal();
  // console.log("this.shoppingCartObj: ", this.shoppingCartObj);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(this.shoppingCartObj));
}

makeOrderId() {
  this.text = "";
  this.possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    this.text += this.possible.charAt(
      Math.floor(Math.random() * this.possible.length)
    );
  }
  return this.text;
}
```

The main thing that I learned, is to keep it simple. As in this case, the html reads item.counter, then just increment/decrement the counter first, as I do within updateCart, which determines if we are incrementing or decrementing by the operator being passed:

```
if (operator === "+") {
  item.counter += 1;
} else {
  item.counter -= 1;
}
```

The other issue that I was having, was when I would go from the product's page to the shopping cart page. If I had increment/decrement an item, then suddenly the shopping cart only contained the last item updated. As a result, once again thanks to @jeto, I used part of his code to reload the shopping cart with everything each time that I would go to either page, within the ngOnInit method:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
  this.filteredProducts.forEach(item => this.moveEverythingToCart(item));
}

moveEverythingToCart(item) {
  if (item.counter > 0) {
    this.refillCart(item);
  }
}

refillCart(item) {
  const index = this.productArr.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.productArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  this.productArr.splice(this.productArr.length, 0, item);

  this.shoppingCartObj = {
    cart: {
      user_id: this.loginSrvc.loginObj.uName,
      orders_id: this.text,
      ts: TimeSt.mTstamp(),
      products: {
        product: this.productArr
      }
    }
  };
  this.getPriceTotal();
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(this.shoppingCartObj));
}
```

And that is it